# Weird border issue on custom Facebook Tab

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe

I'm creating a custom Facebook tab using IFRAME, but for some odd reason this weird border refuses to go away. I've tried the following:

```
table, th, td
{
border: 0px;
}
```

frameborder="0" in the iframe attributes.

and all sorts of CSS attempts. The border just won't go away.

The chrome inspection tool shows the following:

(user agent stylesheet)

```
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
}
```

I have not included that style anywhere in my code. Is there anything I can do to fix this, or is this some kind of Facebook required tab feature? If the border must be there, can I at least have it evenly on all sides?! Hahah.

Refer to this page to see the issue: https://www.facebook.com/hitejinro?sk=app_190322544333196&app_data=visitor_mode

This is what it looks on my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGQbW.jpg

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border is coming from iframe. Your iframe tag doesn't seem to be well formed. change it to

```
<iframe src="http://spuxystudios.com/adwell/psy/index.html" width="850" frameborder="0" height="1900px">....</iframe>
```

Currently it is:

```
<iframe src="http://spuxystudios.com/adwell/psy/index.html" width="850″ frameborder=" 0" height="1900px"></iframe>
```

See there is a quote mismatch on width.